# Title does not appear in frame title when vertical shading (gradient) is applied

Tags: beamer, shading, frame-title

I am trying to apply vertical shading to the title frame but I am unable to get the title into the frame.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{lightgreen}{RGB}{140,238,144}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(3pt)=(darkgreen);
    color(30pt)=(lightgreen)
    }

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
  \vskip2.5pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip3pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0cm,ht=2em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}        

\begin{frame}{Test Title 1}
Sample Text 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test Title 2|}
Sample Text 2
\end{frame}     

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to dig deeper into the frametitle template before inserting the shading, like this:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{vertical shading}
{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    %\vskip-2pt%
    \hbox{\leavevmode
        \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
        \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
        \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
        \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
            \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
                    \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
                    \leftskip0.3cm%
                    \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
                    \insertframetitle%
                    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
                    \strut\par%
                    \else
                    \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
                    \fi%
                    \nointerlineskip
                    \vbox{}%
            \end{minipage}}%
            \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
            \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
            \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
                \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
                \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
                \pgfusepath{clip}
                \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
            \end{pgfpicture}
            \hskip-\paperwidth%
            \box\beamer@tempbox%
        }%
        \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
    }%
    \vskip-2pt
}
```

This replace your `setbeamer template`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{lightgreen}{RGB}{140,238,144}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(3pt)=(darkgreen);
    color(30pt)=(lightgreen)
    }

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
  \vskip2.5pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip3pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{vertical shading}
{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    %\vskip-2pt%
    \hbox{\leavevmode
        \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
        \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
        \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
        \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
            \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
                    \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
                    \leftskip0.3cm%
                    \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
                    \insertframetitle%
                    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
                    \strut\par%
                    \else
                    \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
                    \fi%
                    \nointerlineskip
                    \vbox{}%
            \end{minipage}}%
            \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
            \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
            \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
                \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
                \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
                \pgfusepath{clip}
                \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
            \end{pgfpicture}
            \hskip-\paperwidth%
            \box\beamer@tempbox%
        }%
        \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
    }%
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}        

\begin{frame}{Test Title 1}
Sample Text 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test Title 2|}
Sample Text 2
\end{frame}     

\end{document}
```

[image]